# I added a standard user but I can't switch user or bring up an option to log into standard user

Tags: windows-10, user, standard-user

I have an administrator account on Windows 10. I added a standard user. However, I never get an option to sign in to the standard user. On bootup, only an administrator login screen comes up. On switch user, it brings back the administrator login screen. On log off and log on again it brings up only the administrator login screen.

Comment: How did you add the user account ?